# How to drag items in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery mobile app I have a panel / navigation menu that contains various items I want to be able to drag and drop. I used the following script to achieve that result.

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $( "#items" ).sortable();
    $( "#items" ).disableSelection();
    <!-- Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display -->
    $( "#items" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
      $('#items').button('refresh');

    });
  });
</script>
```

However, this only seems to work on desktop browser because I can't drag and drop on my iPhone or Android phone. Then I did more research and came across this blog.

[Forresst's Blog](http://forresst.github.io/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/)

Blog told me i needed to utilize jquery-ui-touch-punch plugin to make the drag and drop work on mobile devices. So i followed all the instructions on the site and still was not able to get the items to drag on mobile devices. Here is my entire code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <TITLE>RAPTORS</TITLE>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Theme CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script> -->

        <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <!-- TEST Jquery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
        <!-- Style.css  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
        <!-- Testing Drag -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
                $( "#items" ).sortable();
                $( "#items" ).disableSelection();
                <!-- Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display -->
                $( "#items" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
                    $('#items').button('refresh');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <!-- page 1 stufff blah blah -->    
        </div>
        <!-- page 2 -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page2" class="dynPageClass">
            <div data-role="header" data-positiion="fixed">
                <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a>
                <h1>HEAT</h1>
                <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" > 
                 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">WELCOME!</li>
                    <li>Use the menu on the left to navigate <br />and configure the various options.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="panel" id="panel"  data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="push">
                <div>
                    <div id="nav"><h3>Navigation Menu</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div id="items" data-role="button">
                    <a href="#page3" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-cmd" data-role="button">TEAM 1</a>
                    <a href="#page4" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-plus" data-role="button">TEAM 2</a>
                    <a href="#page5" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-man" data-role="button">TEAM 3</a>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-bubble" data-role="button">TEAM 4</a>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
                    <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-cross" data-role="button">LOG OUT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please advice. What have i done wrong? I apologize if its a bad question as i am very new to web development and i am slowly getting the hang of the basics.

This is what i got right now, struggling to get the scroller on mobile device working.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <TITLE>HEAT</TITLE>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
    <!-- Jquery -->

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.js"></script> -->




    <!-- TEST Jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.countdown.css"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>



    <!-- Style.css  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">

<!-- Testing Drag -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $( "#items" ).sortable();
    $( "#items" ).disableSelection();
    // Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display 
      $( "#items" ).on( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
          $('#items').listview('refresh');
    });

    $("#chkSort").on("change", function(){
        var sort = $(this).prop("checked");
        if (sort){
            $( "#items" ).sortable('enable');
        } else {
            $("#items").sortable('disable');
        }

    });
});



</script>


  </head>
  <body>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-positiion="fixed">
        <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#panel" data-role="button" data-icon="flat-menu"></a>
        <h1>HEAT</h1>
        <a data-iconpos="notext" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-icon="home" title="Home">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" > 
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">WELCOME!</li>
            <li>Use the menu on the left to navigate <br />and configure the various options.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel"  data-position="left" data-theme="a" data-display="push">
        <div>
            <div id="nav"><h3>Navigation Menu</h3></div>
            <label>
                <input id="chkSort" type="checkbox" checked="true"  />Allow sorting
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="items" data-role="button">
            <a href="#page3" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-cmd" data-role="button">TEAM 1</a>
            <a href="#page4" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-plus" data-role="button">TEAM 2</a>
            <a href="#page5" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-man" data-role="button">TEAM 3</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-bubble" data-role="button">TEAM 4</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-volume" data-role="button">TEAM 5</a>
            <a href="#" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-settings" data-role="button">TEAM 6</a>
            <a href="#page1" data-transition="fade" data-theme="b" data-icon="flat-cross" data-role="button">LOG OUT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js` file located? You have no relative path on it like the other files. Is it in `js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`?

Comment: It is not located in the js folder it is located in the same folder as my html file. thats why i just put src = "filename"

Comment: You have included touch-punch twice. Remove the first one. In the code the comment should start with // not <!--. Here is a fiddle of your code that works on my android device: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/2/

Comment: @ezanker can you write that as an answer so i can accept your answer and give you a voteup.

Comment: @ezanker, the only problem is now that what if i have 20 items i wont be able to scroll down right??

Comment: Longer lists would be an issue. perhaps you can turn on and off the sorting with a button ($("#items").sortable('disable');) so the user can either sort or scroll. You could also let users select items and provide buttons for moving them up and down in the list instead of dragging.

Comment: @ezanker How exactly would you add a button to turn on and off sorting i did not get what u meant there , is it possible to show by modifying the fiddle you have created?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/3/

Comment: @ezanker I tried this too, this only disables sorting but it still does not allow you to scroll down so if the list is huge you won't be able to see items in bottom.

Comment: @ezanker if any suggestions do let me know. Thanks very much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/6/  added some css to the panel to allow scrolling on the panel contents. Works on my android device...

Comment: @ezanker, Hi this is almost what i was asking for but when i opened it on my device. I am able to drag the item on very top to the very bottom because scroll is working fine. However when i do not allow sorting it does not let me scroll down.  It works fine on my desktop browser but not mobile device. I want to be able to scroll down when sorting check box is not checked. Thanks very very much

Comment: @ezanker, i took your code you have in fiddle too it works fine on desktop browser but in mobile device when i uncheck allow sorting and try scrolling  its not possible

Comment: For me i can visit http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/6/embedded/result/ on my iphone and my android tablet and it scrolls correctly when unchecked

Comment: @ezanker yea when i visit the link u just posted above it seems to be working fine too. Maybe i missed something or maybe there is a mistake in my css. is it possible if i post the code for you to check it out?  i have been trying to figure it out.

Comment: @ezanker Thank you for your time, i just posted it under my original question. i took the code u made in jsfiddle and it also wont let me scroll on mobile device once i uncheck the sorting checkbox.

Comment: Use released jQM 1.4 instead of the alpha version. Where is the panel CSS .ui-panel { bottom: 0 !important;} .ui-panel-inner{ padding-top: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important; height: 98% !important; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}

Comment: I just had to change the js from alpha to a stable release and now it's working fine.

Comment: @ezanker just had a small question is there some way to push the buttons to far left and make the nav menu little bigger so that its easy to see the scroll bar on a mobile device.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/7/ tweak padding-left and padding-right to get what you want.

Comment: @ezanker i did that too, i just noticed though that if i have a big team name i cant see it for example if the name is "Sacremento Kings" i just see "Sacremento..." on the button. i don't wana push the panel more right because it might look ugly. Was thinking of some creative way to keep buttons readable and give more room to scrollbar. do let me know if u know some quick trick. thanks again.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/8/ just add css rule for white-space setting it to normal instead of nowrap

Comment: @ezanker Thanks for your help. You have helped so much i had one last question its actually different i have posted it if you can take a look and provide guidance it would be great since you are kind of familiar with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have included touch-punch twice. Remove the first one.

In the code the comment should start with // not

> Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/2/)** that works on my Android device.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
    $( "#items" ).sortable();
    $( "#items" ).disableSelection();
    //Refresh list to the end of sort to have a correct display
    $( "#items" ).on( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
          $('#items').listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Because the list can be longer then the viewport height it is useful to turn off sorting and allow the user to scroll via touch. For this I added a checkbox above the list that toggles on and off the sorting:

```
$("#chkSort").on("change", function(){
    var sort = $(this).prop("checked");
    if (sort){
        $( "#items" ).sortable('enable');
    } else {
        $("#items").sortable('disable');
    }               
});
```

In addition I added some css to the panel to keep it at 100% height and allow the inner panel to overflow for sorting:

```
.ui-panel {
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
.ui-panel-inner{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 98% !important;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

> Here is the updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3rR6J/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery-ui library which makes drag & drop possible. And toucpunch which fixes jquery-ui to be compatible with mobile touch events http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I have successfully used this technique to make http://www.impresspages.org drag & drop

Comment: Thanks for an advice. The question is overcomplicated. And the answer would become overcomplicated too. Let's keep it small. If you like those "fat" answers, please up-vote them. I like professional and precise solutions without bla bla bla...